# grafana singlestat panel shows random value for different time interval

Tags: graphite, grafana, statsd

I have singlestat panel that display a value of a gauge.
The value is displayed correctly for Time Range: Today.
[image]

However, If I change the time range to yesterday the panel shows a very large value.

[image]

I can't explain why or what I'm doing wrong. Have no idea how it computes such a value since all the values are around 1900 figure. I'm using graphite as a datasource and I'm pretty sure I send the correct values.
Retention policy is configured like this:

```
retentions = 10s:1d,5m:365d,1h:5y
```

Any idea is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy metric to Graph panel and check how metric is look like, for today, yesterday or any other period of time. 
If you need to pick up only last value - go to "Metrics" tab and change "Max data points" to 1 or 2 (default is average of last 100 points)

Comment: I have same series graphed as a bar chart and looks fine. I haven't tried to put 1-2 max data point for singlestat panel but i doubt it will change anything since all the points fetched have very large values like the one from screenshot.

Comment: I tried setting "max data points" to 1-2 but no change at all. Still getting some very large values like the one from screenshot.

Comment: I think more info needed then. How metric looks like (you can hide metric name but left functions), how it's graph look like, on day and week scale, how singlestat looks like on day and week scale.

Comment: I believe it has to do with aggregation method I use. 57510 / 1920 = 29 and always getting values that perfectly divide by 1920. Apparently, there's something wrong there. I'll investigate this and come back. Thanks!